# Returned std::string by value - why does the internal buffer point to existing memory?

Tags: c++

```cpp
class StringPool
{
public:
    explicit StringPool(size_t reserve = 0);
    std::string Pool(const std::string& str);

private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_pool;
};

StringPool::StringPool(size_t reserve)
{
    if (reserve > 0)
        m_pool.reserve(reserve);
}

std::string StringPool::Pool(const std::string& str)
{
    if (str.empty())
        return std::string();

    auto it = std::find(m_pool.begin(), m_pool.end(), str);
    if (it != m_pool.end())
        return *it;
    m_pool.push_back(str);
    return str;
};

int main()
{
    StringPool spool;   
    std::string tmp;
    spool.Pool("HELLO");
    spool.Pool("WORLD");
    tmp = spool.Pool("HELLO");
}
```

Why does the internal buffer of `tmp` have the same address of the returned element?
Is `tmp`s internal buffer just simply assigned to the pointer of the returned value due to RVO?

I'm unsure of what language mechanisms facilitate this assignment.

Comment: Where do you calculate the addresses?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _"address of the returned element"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the internal buffer of tmp have the same address of the returned element?

I assume that by  returned "element", you mean the internal buffer of the returned string object.

It is unclear whether you refer to the internal address of `tmp` before the assignment or after the assignment. In practice, the address typically remains the same in this case, and thus the address would **not** be the same as the address of the returned string's buffer.

The move assignment could change `tmp` to have the internal address of the returned string. In practice, this won't happen unless the string is long enough to exceed the short string optimisation.

As for why: Because that's how the move assignment of `std::string` was implemented by your standard library.

> just simply assigned to the pointer of the returned value due to RVO?

There may indeed be RVO on the line `return std::string();`. RVO has no effect on the internal address of `tmp`.

Comment: Could you clarify further on the RVO comment. The returned object is an element in the pool - not the argument itself.

Comment: @wubzorz I didn't notice that there were more than one return statement. I'll fix the answer. Edit: Fixed.

Comment: In that case - is the returned string placed in a temporary copy which is then subsequently moved from the temporary into `tmp`?

Comment: @wubzorz Probably. RVO might be impossible given that it cannot be used in all return paths. On the other hand, if the function call is expanded inline, then all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks @eerorika - much appreciated.

The intent of the code was to use pooling for common strings.
In that case - should I then be returning a reference to the accessed element of the vector if found?

Comment: @wubzorz Depends. What reference would you return when the string isn't found?